# Android - How to avoid deadlock between the two runOnUIThread calls

Tags: android, multithreading, deadlock

I have this process which runs through some "if"s depending if a user insert or eject a memory pen drive:

```
int userStatus = StopActivity.USER_HAS_NEVER_INSERTED_MEMORY;

while (true) {

    File usbDirectoryFile = new File(usbDirectory);

    if (usbDirectoryFile.exists()) {

        verMasInfoDirectory = usbDirectory + File.separator + "vermasinfo";
        File verMasInfoDirectoryFile = new File(verMasInfoDirectory);

        if (verMasInfoDirectoryFile.exists()) {

            break;

        } else if (userStatus != StopActivity.USER_HAS_BEEN_NOTIFIED) {

            userStatus = StopActivity.USER_HAS_BEEN_NOTIFIED;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(StopActivity.this, R.string.stop_activity_directory_not_exists_toast_text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    } else if (userStatus == StopActivity.USER_HAS_BEEN_NOTIFIED) {

        userStatus = StopActivity.USER_HAS_NOT_BEEN_NOTIFIED;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(StopActivity.this, R.string.stop_activity_ejected_memory_toast_text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        });
    }
    usbDirectoryFile = null;
}
```

The problem is that when the user insert/eject the pen drive fast, both calls to runOnUIThread can cause a deadlock.

How can I avoid that deadlock?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These calls cannot cause a deadlock. First, they are run one at a time by the system. That is, one runs (on the event thread) to completion (until the `run()` method returns) before the other one is dequeued and run by the event thread. Second, the runnables are not locking resources, so there is no reason for a deadlock.

Perhaps you are concerned about two `Toast`s on the screen at the same time (since each `Toast` is on display for a time after `show()` returns). The only problem with this is that one will hide the other; however, there is still no deadlock.

If your app is deadlocking, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Following your answer (disregarding the deadlock), I have added a `Thread.sleep(100)` just before the end of the while and now works perfectly.

Just to let this clear: Do you know why in many cases with a sleep things will work?

Comment: @Jorgesmash - I suspect that your loop was placing runnables onto the event thread queue much faster than they could be consumed, eventually overwhelming the system. I'm not quite sure what you expect the loop to do, but if I traced through it correctly, it was popping up Toasts as fast as possible, waiting for some file to appear. I don't know what the purpose of this would be, but it doesn't seem like the right approach to notifying the user about something.